# Editing docbook

Tags: text-editing, docbook

I need to edit a docbook resource with a decent, cross platform WYSIWYG editor, being also able to include latex style formulas, images and svg plots. Then, I need to create pdf, html and import the data on a drupal website for public online browsing.

Do you have any hints ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://superuser.com/questions/78028/is-there-a-tool-that-helps-writing-a-book-with-docbook-code

Answer (score 1):

XMLmind has a free, personal edition. It's a bit clunky, but works.

Images will work find in XMLmind, as will svgs (though you need to add the svg DTD to your file)

If you want latex, you'll have to generate images and include the images in your docbook file, otherwise look at MathML.