# Is there a Tool that helps writing a Book with DocBook Code?

Tags: docbook

DocBook seems to be nice, but is there a Tool that helps using it? I mean something that would instantly show how it looks or allows editing more easily by selecting a word and then hitting a button to format it somehow, or to enter a paragraph, a index, a footnote, whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [dbkeditor](http://dbkeditor.sourceforge.net/).  It's intended to help someone learn how to write docbooks XML format.  It's not too fancy, but does help with some of the complexity.  Runs as a standalone jar.

Comment: This is super-barebones. For a more feature-rich editor with these features, there isn't a free alternative available. The most popular paid programs for visually editing Docbook are oXygen and XMetal.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [asciidoc](http://www.methods.co.nz/asciidoc/). It's a simplified language that gives you access to most docbook features without needing to write directing in Docbook's verbose tag structure.

Comment: The question is about docbook

Comment: This answer actually is about Docbook. You can use asciidoc as a "front-end" language, instead of writing in Docbook directly. Re-reading the question though, this actually doesn't answer it, since it looks this was requesting a visual/wysiwyg-type editor.

Answer (score 0):

Get [Yelp](http://live.gnome.org/Yelp).  It opens Docbook files natively, renders them nicely, shows a browseable tree-view of the document on the left, and reloads instantly when you hit control-R.

Comment: How would you author with this??

Comment: It's a viewer, not an editor.  I assumed when he said "instantly show how it looks" I thought that's *all* he wanted.  For editing, any XML editor will do.  If you need WYSIWYG, then buy FrameMaker.

Answer (score -1):

[LyX](http://www.lyx.org/) is what you're looking for.

Comment: It says nothing about docbook, only Tex, LaTex