# Good open-source DocBook editing tools?

Tags: editing, documentation, docbook

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a Tool that helps writing a Book with DocBook Code?](https://superuser.com/questions/78028/is-there-a-tool-that-helps-writing-a-book-with-docbook-code)

I am looking for a good open-source application to help with editing DocBook documents.

By good I mean:

- stable
- documented
- active (project)

I have already tried [Conglomerate](http://conglomerate.org/index.html) but it crashes frequently for me.